# gspread package not updated on pip or conda

Tags: python, pip, gspread

I'm trying to use get_worksheet_by_id function from the gspread package.

I can see the function is available in https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py

It's also listed in documentation.

But I it's missing in pip and conda repositories. As a result I'm not able to use it.
https://pypi.org/project/gspread/#files
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gspread/files

Not sure where to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see if you look at the blame, the function was only added by [this commit](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/commit/011b44c0d64d10aa7f939b7c3b8bf0b99195b9dc), which is from march 2021. The latest version available from pypi and conda-forge is however from february. That is why you don't have if when you install through these channels.

Some suggestions:

- You could simply edit the code of the library in your `site-packages`
- Install from the github sources, either by cloning the repo and doing `python setup.py install` or through `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/burnash/gspread`
- Create an issue on the github repo and ask that the version on conda-forge/pypi is updated to include this feature.